# Android logic for special calculator

Tags: android, logic

I was trying to make a calculator that takes a input of number of panels from user. Then it will show some options based on the combination of different panel sizes- 3, 5, 7, 11, 13. The combined value could be +- of 1 or 2 of total panel sizes. Output will show in the format: 2 x 9 Panel, 1 x 7 Panel OR 2 X 13 Panel OR 3 X 9 Pane.

Here is the calculation code:

```
int available_ar[]= {13, 11, 7, 5, 3};
int result_ar[]= {0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
int[][] panel_options_ar= new int[10][5];

// ********Calculation Part********
for (int k=0 ; k< result_ar.length ; k++)
{
    result_ar[k]= panel-2+k;
}

for (i=0; i< result_ar.length; i++){
    x= result_ar[i];
    for (j=0; j< available_ar.length; j++){
        while (x>=available_ar[j]){
            x= x- available_ar[j];
            panel_options_ar[i][j]= panel_options_ar[i][j]+ 1;
        }
    }
}

// ********Display part********
for (i=0; i< result_ar.length; i++){
    for (j=0; j< available_ar.length; j++){
        if (panel_options_ar[i][j]> 0){
           text1 = text1+" "+panel_options_ar[i][j]+" x "+available_ar[j]+" Panel,";
        }
        else {
           break;
        }
    }
    text= text+"\n"+text1; 
}
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Output shows:

```
10 X 13 panel,
10 X 13 panel, 10 X 13 panel, 
10 X 13 panel, 10 X 13 panel, 10 X 13 panel,
10 X 13 panel, 10 X 13 panel, 10 X 13 panel, 10 X 13 panel,
10 X 13 panel, 10 X 13 panel, 10 X 13 panel, 10 X 13 panel, 10 X 13 panel,
```

This is not my expected output. I think I've made some mistakes in the logic. But I couldn't find the problem.

Comment: are you missing 9 in the list of panel sizes? because I'm really confused by the example you've given. Can you give a better example of what you want to achieve?

Comment: @Gayan there is no panel size of 9. For an example: say user wants 25 panel (user input). Then the calculator will give output- 2x9 Panel, 1x7 Panel (total 25) OR 2x13 Panel (total 26) OR 3x9 Panel (total 27). So, the output is +- of 1 or 2 of input panel size.